# Node.js webscraping authentication with robost

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I am having trouble with the post request for logging into a site to scrape the data. I need to give uname password and scraped robust value.
am trying to take data's from the web site. Now whole scraping process is confusing. am using Node js. Here is the code:**

```
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var qs = require('querystring');

    url = "myweblik";
    //headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    var j = request.jar();
    var request = request.defaults({jar:j})

    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      temperature = $("[name='chkLoginForm']").text();  
      console.log(temperature);
    });

    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
     //process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);

     if (chunk != 'undefine') {

    var uname = "XXXXX";
    var pwd = "YYYYY";
    var credentials = '?{actionForm.userName}='+uname+'&{actionForm.password}='+pwd+'&{actionForm.qreply}='+chunk;


    request.post({
        uri: 'Myweblink',
            headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: qs.stringify(credentials)
    },
       function(err, res, body){

            if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Login failed'));
            return;
        }
    request('responsemy weblink', function(err, res, body) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('error occure');
                callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
                return;
            }
    //console.log(body);
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var text = $('.tablebody').text();
    console.log(body);
        });
    });

    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending data in url query format. However, for the post data to be sent to the `request`, I would suggest convert the `credentials` variable to an object like below -

```
var credentials = {
    userName : uname,
    password : pwd,
    qreply :chunk
};
```

and then in your `request` `POST` method send this data as -

```
request.post({
    uri: 'Myweblink',
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    form: credentials
},
```

Hope this helps.